# Testing opengles program on PC

Tags: android, c++, windows, ubuntu, opengl-es

I'm working on some effects in Opengl ES 1.x .
I've written the code in c++ so i can use it in android (using NDK) and iphone.
How can i build a project and run it on the PC without android emulator or iphone ?
I mean ; I still do not know how to use NDK , but i do know Opengl ES.
I have Ubuntu and windows on my PC .

Comment: This seems to be a nice overview of your options: http://www.g-truc.net/post-0457.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL is crossplatform. opengl es is just a subset of opengl, so you'll have to take care what you are using (it must be supported in opengl es).

Create an example program that will create a window, and execute opengl functions. Build your program on PC, and execute. You'll still have to try your program in the emulator (or phone)

Comment: do you mean writing an opengl program that compatible with opengl es : use opengl functions thats also opengl es using ?? is that the only solution ??

Comment: @saeedhardan Yes to both questions. Otherwise you need the emulator

Comment: finally i decided to learn ndk , and now i'm using it and testing on my phone directly .

Answer (score 0):

In case you are interested there are opengl es emulators provided by GPU manufacturers which is good for testing opengl es code on the desktop.

This is an [emulator](http://www.malideveloper.com/developer-resources/tools/opengl-es-20-emulator.php) I use. It is emulator for MALI GPUs which are present in many android phone such galaxy S2 S3 etc.

Comment: i think i like your idea , i took a look at the samples that came with the installer , theres one thing that bothers me since i'm not that into egl i don't know when to use eglSwapBuffers() .

Comment: theres another problem my graphics card doesn't support one of the extensions needed by the opengl es emulator , bummer -_-